# Referencing Public Variable Between Subs

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I'm trying to define some variables (for row/column referencing) and use it in multiple subs but I'm having some issue:

Update - fixed earlier issue. Now I can get the columns to cycle. However , when the Column AE is visible and someone clicks next, I want the process to hide the current row, reset to Column E i.e. 5, and show the next row, then cycle through to column AE again. At the moment, when I click 'Next' when AE is showing, it just hides the current row and doesn't show the next row or hid the columns D:AE....

The code it's working from is:

```
If Columns("AE:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
Columns("D:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Rows(Question).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Question = Question + 1
Rows(Question).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Brand = 5
End If
```

Full code here:

```
   Public Brand As Integer
' this will hold the current visible column
Public Question As Integer
' this will hold the current visible row

Sub StartQuestionnaire()

' this sends the user to two different questionnaire formats
If ThisWorkbook.Team = 1 Then Call BrandManager
If ThisWorkbook.Team = 0 Then Call CrossFunctionalTeam
End Sub

Sub BrandManager()
'Questionnaire format 1
Brand = 5
Question = 10
Columns(Brand).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows(Question).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub

Sub CrossFunctionalTeam()
'Questionnaire format 2
If ThisWorkbook.Team = 0 Then
Columns("E:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Select
End If
End Sub

Sub NextButton()
'if a Brand Manager, cycle to the next column question until column AE is reached, then move to next row and show first question only
If ThisWorkbook.Team = 1 Then
If Columns("AE:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
Columns("D:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Rows(Question).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Question = Question + 1
Rows(Question).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Brand = 5
End If
If Columns("AE:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
Columns(Brand).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Brand = Brand + 1
Columns(Brand).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End If

'if a Cross Funtional team user, Next button should cycle to the next row of questions
If ThisWorkbook.Team = 0 Then
Question = 10
Rows(Question).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Question = Question + 1
Rows(Question).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Using object names as variable names isn't recommended.  Try changing them then post a new question if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to say with `Range(Row)`? Say, `Range(25)`?
If I'm not misunderstanding and according to your code it must look as:

```
Sub NextButton()
' ...
If Range("AE:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
' ...
Rows(Row).Hidden = True ' Range(Row).EntireRow.Hidden 
Row = Row + 1
Columns(Row).Hidden = False ' Range(Row).EntireColumn.Hidden
' ...
```